# What could cause "Application lahmuTen has not been registered" when all I did was init the app with react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native

Commands:

```
react-native init lahmuTen
cd lahmuTen/
ls
react-native run-ios
```

Result:

```
Application lahmuTen has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.

runApplication
    AppRegistry.js:99
__callFunction
    MessageQueue.js:236
<unknown>
    MessageQueue.js:108
guard
    MessageQueue.js:46
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    MessageQueue.js:107
```

Complete code:

```
$ cat index.ios.js 
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class lahmuTen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('lahmuTen', () => lahmuTen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The React-Native packager has to be running **and** it has to be running from the same directory as the application.

```
cd lahmuTen    
react-native start
# open new Terminal in same folder
react-native run-ios
```